# How does a std::function object which return a std::function work when call by operator()?

Tags: c++

## Sample:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
std::function<void(int)> Foo()
{
    int v = 1;
    int r = 2;
    auto l = [v, r](int i)
    {
        std::cout << v << " " << r << " " << i << std::endl;
    };
    return l;
}

int main()
{
    auto func = Foo();
    func(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Why `func(3)` can pass `3` to i which is the formal argument of the lambda in Foo(). I can't think out. thanks.

Comment: You don't have a *"`std::function` object which return a lambda"*. `Foo` returns a `std::function` which you have defined using a lambda

Comment: Also `func(3)` invokes *undefined behavior* because the `&r` of your lambda captures refers to a variable whose lifetime has ended by the time you invoke the function (a dangling reference)

Comment: It's pointless to try to reason about a program that invokes UB - it may do *anything*. Fix your UB bugs first, *then* try to reason about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: You don't pass your argument 3 into a function Foo. You pass it to a **method** of an **object** `func`.

A bit more detailed explanation is below.

---

First of all, I would like to clarify what a *lambda* is. A *lambda* in C++ is nothing more than an anonymous functor class, so essentially just a syntactic sugar. A *closure* is an instance of a lambda type. However, quite often you can hear words "lambda" and "closure" being used interchangeably.

So within your function `Foo()` you create a *closure* object `l`

```
auto l = [v, r](int i)
{
    std::cout << v << " " << r << " " << i << std::endl;
};
```

which would be technically equivalent to this code:

```
struct Functor
{
    Functor(int v, int r) : v_(v), r_(r) {}

    void operator ()(int i) const {
        std::cout << v_ << " " << r_ << " " << i << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int v_;
    int r_;
};
Functor l(v, r);
```

Now, on the next line you return an std::function object.

```
return l; // actually creates std::function<void(int)>(l) and returns it
```

So in your `main` function a `func` is just an *object* which stores *copies* of values `v, r` obtained during a call to `Foo()` and defines `operator()`, similar to the struct above.
Therefore, calling `func(3)` you actually invoke an object method on a concrete object func, and without syntactic sugar it looks like `func.operator()(3)`.

Here's a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc0cfc9f3fc132d2) to illustrate my point.

Hope that helps to resolve your confusion.

Comment: thx, I didn't notice that the codes return a std::function<void(int)> and regard it as abstract magic in c++. so `Foo` is just a trival function.